# Center Picker in View when .labelsHidden()

Tags: swiftui, picker

I'm showing a SwiftUI DatePicker with the datePickerStyle of type WheelDatePickerStyle(). It's inside a Section, which is within a Form. As I'm showing a Section Header, I don't want to show the Picker's label. When choosing .labelsHidden(), however, the Picker just moves to the left and leaves some space to the left.

How can I either center the picker, or make sure that it takes up the full width of the Section / Form?

```
DatePicker("Please enter a time", selection: $time, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
    .labelsHidden()
    .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
```

Comment: Could you include your code please?

Comment: This code snippet is working as you want, so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the label. Just like the following:

```
   DatePicker("", selection: $time, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
    // .labelsHidden()
    .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
```

Another simple way is to use `HStack` with `Spacer()` at both sides.

```
HStack{
    Spacer()
    DatePicker.init(selection: $time, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute, label: {
        EmptyView()
        })
        .labelsHidden().datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
    Spacer()
    }
```

Comment: I like the second suggestion! The label is also used for screen readers, so an empty String isn't an ideal option.

Answer (score 12):

```
DatePicker("Please enter a time", selection: $time, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
    .labelsHidden()
    .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
```

Comment: The ```.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)``` did the trick for me